# SQL SMS 2008 -Count column ids and count duplicate ids if createddate is greater than 3 months between ids

Tags: sql-server

*Edit (Hopefully to be more clear)

Table below, I would like to count ids and count duplicate ids where the createddate has a gap of 3 months or more for that ID.

Query I have so far...

```
if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null 
        begin drop table #temp end
select
top 100
 a.id, a.CreatedDate

into #temp
from tbl a

where 1=1
--and year(CreatedDate) = '2015'

if object_id('tempdb..#temp2') is not null 
        begin drop table #temp2 end
select t.id, count(t.id) as Total_Cnt
into #temp2
from #temp t
group by id

select distinct #temp2.Total_Cnt, #temp2.id, #temp.CreatedDate, DENSE_RANK()     over (partition by #temp.id order by createddate) RK
from #temp2
inner join #temp on #temp2.id = #temp.id

where 1=1

order by Total_Cnt desc
```

Results:

```
Total_cnt    id    createddate            rk
  3           1       01-01-2015          1
  3           1       03-02-2015          2
  3           1       01-02-2015          3               
  2           2       05-01-2015          1
  2           2       05-02-2015          2
  1           3       06-01-2015          1
  1           4       07-01-2015          1
```

Count ids and only count duplicate ids when the createddate from the id is greater than 3 months.

Something like this...

```
Total_cnt    id     Countwith3monthgap
  3           1            2
  2           2            1
  1           3            1
  1           4            1
```

Comment: Can you explain better where does that `7` on count column came from?  It seems that your sample data does not match the desired result. If that is the case, please, edit your question so we can understand it better.

Comment: @JorgeCampos TotalCount would be the SUM of the count column. I'll remove the TotalCount column, thanks.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @shawnt00 SQL Mgmt Studio 2008

Comment: Still rearching, haven't found an answer that works for me. The answers below are not what I'm looking for. Hopefully I can solve in time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cte and ROW_NUMBER to get your order and self join the cte based on the order..

```
WITH cte AS 
(   SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreatedDate) Rn
    FROM
        Test
)
SELECT
    c1.ID,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN c2.CreatedDate IS NULL THEN 1
                WHEN c1.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(month,3,c2.CreatedDate) THEN 1
            END)
FROM
    cte c1
    LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c1.ID = c2.ID
                        AND c1.RN = c2.RN + 1
GROUP BY
    c1.ID
```

You also need to use a conditional count where the Previous CreatedDate is null or if the Current CreatedDate is >= the Previous CreatedDate + 3 months

If you happen to be using SQL 2012+ you can also use LAG here to get the same result

```
SELECT
    ID,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ID, 
        CreatedDate CurrentDate,
        LAG(CreatedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreatedDate) PreviousDate
    FROM 
        Test
    ) T
WHERE
    PreviousDate IS NULL 
    OR CurrentDate >= DATEADD(month, 3, PreviousDate)
GROUP BY 
    ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lag to get the previous date, Null for the first in the list

```
SELECT 
id,
lag(CreatedDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS PreviousCreateDate,
CreatedDate
FROM @t
```

You can use that as a subquery and get the difference in months using DATEDIFF

```
SELECT sub.id,DATEDiff(month, sub.PreviousCreateDate ,sub.CreatedDate) 
FROM (SELECT 
      id,
      lag(CreatedDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS PreviousCreateDate,
      CreatedDate
      FROM @t) sub
WHERE DATEDiff(month, sub.PreviousCreateDate ,sub.CreatedDate) >=3
OR sub.PreviousCreateDate IS NULL
```

You can then take your totals

```
SELECT sub.id,COUNT(sub.id) as cnt
FROM (SELECT 
      id,
      lag(CreatedDate,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY CreatedDate) AS PreviousCreateDate,
      CreatedDate
      FROM @t) sub
WHERE DATEDIFF(month, sub.PreviousCreateDate ,sub.CreatedDate) >=3
OR sub.PreviousCreateDate IS NULL
GROUP BY sub.id
```

Note that using datediff the last day of january is three months before the first day of march. That appears to be the logic you were after.

You might want to define your three month gap criteria as

```
WHERE sub.PreviousCreateDate  <= DATEADD(month, -3, sub.CreatedDate)
OR sub.PreviousCreateDate IS NULL
```

or

```
WHERE sub.CreatedDate >= DATEADD(month, +3, sub.PreviousCreateDate )
OR sub.PreviousCreateDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your desired definition of three-month gap doesn't coincide with `datediff()`'s. Most of the logic here is to look back at the previous date and decide if the gap is big enough to qualify.

When `datediff()` counts three months difference we still need to make sure the day of month is later than the first one (*per example and ID 5*). If difference is more than three months then we're good automatically.

But I'm also assuming that you would want to treat the distance from November 30th to February 28th (or 29th in a leap year) as a full three months because the end date falls on the final day of the month. By adjusting the end date by an extra day this is an easy scenario to snag as it will bump the date into the following month and increase the month difference by one as well. If that's not what you want then just remove the `dateadd(day, 1, ...)` portion and use only the raw `CreatedDate` value.

You sample data is limited so I'm also making the assumption that the gaps are measure between consecutive dates. If you're wanting to find blocks of runs that don't span more than three months across the set, then that's a different problem and you should clarify with more information.

*Since you've indicated that you're probably on SQL Server 2008 you'll have to do without the `lag()` function. Although the first query could be adjusted for that it's likely easier to go with the second approach at the end.*

```
with diffs as (
    select
        ID,
        row_number() over (partition by ID order by CreatedDate) as RN,
        case when
            datediff(
                month,
                lag(CreatedDate, 1) over (partition by ID order by CreatedDate),
                CreatedDate
            ) = 3
            and
            datepart(
                day,
                lag(CreatedDate, 1) over (partition by ID order by CreatedDate)
            ) <= datepart(day, CreatedDate)
            or
            datediff(
                month,
                lag(CreatedDate, 1) over (partition by ID order by CreatedDate),
                /* adding one day to handle gaps like Nov30 - Feb28/29 and Jan31 - Apr30 */
                dateadd(day, 1, CreatedDate)
            ) >= 4
            then 1
            else 0
        end as GapFlag
    from <T> /* <--- your table name here */
), gaps as (
    select
        ID, RN,
        sum(1 + GapFlag) over (partition by ID order by RN) as Counter
    from diffs
)
select ID, count(distinct Counter - RN) as "Count"
from gaps
group by ID
```

The rest of the logic is a typical gaps and islands scenario looking for holes in the `sum(1 + GapCount)` sequence with the offset of 1 acting pretty much like `row_number()`.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/61b12/3

JamieD77's approach is also valid. I was originally thinking your problem involved more than looking at the rows in sequence. Here's how I would tweak it for the gap definition I've been running with:

```
with data as (
    select ID, CreatedDate, row_number() over (partition by ID order by CreatedDate) as RN
    from T
)
select ID, count(*) as "Count"
from data d1 left outer join data d0
    on d0.ID = d1.ID and d0.RN = d1.RN - 1 /* connect to the one before */
where
        datediff(month, d0.CreatedDate, d1.CreatedDate) = 3
    and datepart(day, d0.CreatedDate) <= datepart(day, d0.CreatedDate)
    or  datediff(month, d0.CreatedDate, dateadd(day, 1, d0.CreatedDate)) >= 4
    or  d0.ID is null
group by ID
```

**Edit**: You have changed the question since yesterday.

Change this line in the first query to include the total count:

```
...
select count(*) as TotalCnt, ID, count(distinct Counter - RN) as GapCount
...
```

Second would look like:

```
with data as (
    select ID, CreatedDate, row_number() over (partition by ID order by CreatedDate) as RN
    from T
)
select
    count(*) as TotalCnt, ID,
    count(case when 
            datediff(month, d0.CreatedDate, d1.CreatedDate) = 3
        and datepart(day, d0.CreatedDate) <= datepart(day, d0.CreatedDate)
        or  datediff(month, d0.CreatedDate, dateadd(day, 1, d0.CreatedDate)) >= 4
        or  d0.ID is null then 1 end
    ) as GapCount
from data d1 left outer join data d0
    on d0.ID = d1.ID and d0.RN = d1.RN - 1 /* connect to the one before */
where
group by ID
```